# behavior of open (file) in I/O

Tags: c++, file, io

On running these codes:

```
std::fstream f;
if(f.open("n",std::fstream::in))           //ERROR
```

The error received is:

> could not convert ‘f.std::basic_fstream::open(((const char*)"n"), ((std::ios_base::openmode)std::ios_base::in))’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’

But on running the same code with `filebuf` object it runs fine:

```
std::filebuf f;
if(f.open("n",std::fstream::in))          //works fine
```

why is that happening when both `fstream` and `filebuf` object can be used to call `open`?

Comment: `fstream::open` doesn't return anything. `filebuf::open` returns `this` if the file opened and otherwise NULL.

Comment: They're not the same function. `fstream` has its own `open` method (that calls `filebuf::open` internally) and simply decides not to return anything. If the file could not open it will be reflected in the "stream state" which you can check by doing `if (f.fail())` after the `open` call.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Got it, thanks!! I was confused in how one function returns differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fstream` has its own `open` method (that calls `filebuf::open` internally) and simply decides not to return anything. If the file could not open it will be reflected in the "stream state" which you can check by doing `if (f.fail())` after the `open` call.